# Rails 5 - Add nested form link not working after saving failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form for sales invoice and a nested form inside it for the payment records. Basically, I add a new invoice then I register the payment received from the client which related to that invoice. That works fine when I add a new invoice (in the new view), but if saving the invoice fails, the link to add new nested form (payment record) behave in a strange way, so when it gets clicked it takes me to the index page instead of adding new nested form.

```
The sale invoice view code
.
.
<%= f.simple_fields_for(:sales_payment_records) do |item| %>
  <%= render 'sales_payment_records', f: item %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to_add_pay_record_sale ' add  ', f, :sales_payment_records, 'sales_payment_records' %>
.
. countinue the sale invoice view code
```

The sales invoice helper:

```
module SaleInvoicesHelper
def link_to_add_pay_record_sale(name, f, association, partial_name)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new 
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.simple_fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |item|
        render(partial_name, f: item)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields btn btn-sm btn-warning fa fa-plus ", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
end
```

when I put the courser on the add link, I see url link is "http://localhost:3000/sale_invoices/new#", but after the saving failure it becomes "http://localhost:3000/sale_invoices#"...
Any suggestions!!

Comment: ohh man just use this https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use cocoon, since my other nested forms are complicated more than the one in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believed your source code above using [railcast episode 196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised) and you missing the jquery part which generate the new record for next row

here is the jquery part with coffee script format:

```
jQuery ->
  $('form').on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
    $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
    $(this).closest('fieldset').hide()
    event.preventDefault()

  $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
    time = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
    event.preventDefault()
```

you should or may change the part $(this).before... to follow your html structure tag inside your table
so the new row (tr) so the new row inserted on bottom of  your current table

Comment: Thank you, actually, I already have the jQuery code, but your answer shows me that I have the different names for the class in the link_to and in the JQ $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields'..  which was main mistake. In addition, I have changed the $('form').on to be $(document).on... for some reasons I had issues with reloading the pasge when using 'form'..now everthing is working :)